# Get-mailboxdatabase | clean-mailboxdatabase - not on all databases

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We have a few Servers/Databases and I'd like to write a cleanDB script that only runs on half of them.  The names that i want to alter start with exch-ms-01, 02, 03, 04.  We have 3 others that I do not want to include in the clean.

Get-mailboxDatabase -server exch-ms-* returns : there are multiple exchange servers matching the identity "exch-ms-*".  Please specify a unique value.

Comment: `Foreach($server in $servers) { Get-mailboxDatabase -server $server}` ... the `-server` parameter does not accept a list of servers. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124924(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

dug around and found something that works.

```
get-mailboxserver | Where-Object {($_.name -like "exch-ms-*")} | get-mailboxdatabase | clean-mailboxdatabase
```